# Using color as string in mixin parameter (lesscss)

Tags: css, less

Basically I want to use a string that may contain keywords like 'red','green' or 'blue'. However LESS converts it to hex values like #ff0000 instead of red.

---

Example

```
.foo(@className) {
    .bar_@{className} { color: white; }
}
```

Using the mixin

```
.foo(red);
```

should output

```
.bar_red { color: white; }
```

but instead it shows

```
.bar_#ff0000 { color: white; }
```

How do I escape or cast the parameter as a string? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `.foo(~"red");` might work...